# Changing sprite frame on mouseEnter in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an assets file under the name of play-button with `texture type=sprite2D` and `Sprite Mode = Multiple`, it contains 2 different frames: `play-button0` and `play-button1`

i have attached a c# script file for this asset with the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Play_btn : MonoBehaviour {

    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
    Sprite s1;
    Sprite s2;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (spriteRenderer.sprite == null)
                        spriteRenderer.sprite = s1;
    }
    void OnMouseDown() {
        Application.LoadLevel("Levels");
    }
    void OnMouseEnter() {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = s2;
    }
    void OnMouseExit() {
        //spriteRenderer.sprite = sprite1;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

As you can see i am trying to change the frame `onMouseEnter` and `OnMouseExit` but when the `mouseEnter` the play button a null reference error is occurring and a blank object is displaying on the screen, can anyone help me in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see, the Sprites s1 & s2 are not public (so you could not have assigned it via the inspector), and there's no code where you assign the s1 & s2 variables.

**Solution**
Make the Sprites s1 and s2 public, and assign them.